# How to add some value to the one, two,... greater (smaller) elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I tell Mathematica to add a certain value ---not necessarily the same for all elements --- to the two, three, four... greater or smaller elements of a list without sorting it.

Comment: Use `Ordering[]` to fetch their positions in the list, and then you can do an assignment like `list[[pos]] += value`.

Comment: it will help if you make a MWE, giving small input and what is the output you want.

Comment: Probably simplest to thread over J.-M. 's suggestion, i.e.`list = {1, 4, 23, 49, 27, 18, 3}; valueDelta ={12,5,7,3}; list[[Ordering[list, -Length[valueDelta]]]] += valueDelta;`  to increment 4 max values;   otherwise `list[[Ordering[list, +Length[valueDelta]]]] += valueDelta;` to increment 4 min values.  See Ordering documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html) for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {10}]
```

> example b= {3, 4, 3, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 2, 2}

```
value = {1, 2, 3, 4};
funcMax[x_List, y_Integer, z_List] := 
 ReplacePart[x, 
  Rule @@@ Partition[Riffle[ Ordering[x][[-y ;; -1]], z], 2]]
funcMax[b, 4, value]
```

output

> {3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2}

to do the same for the minimun just replace `Ordering[x][[-y ;; -1]]` with `Ordering[x][[1 ;; y]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[f1, f2]
f1 = MapAt[#, #2, List /@ Ordering[##2]] &;
f2 = Module[{ord = Ordering[##2]}, ReplacePart[#2, Thread[ord -> (# /@ #2[[ord]])]]] &;
```

Examples:

```
list = {1, 4, 3, 7, 2, 7, 6, 4, 8, 2, 3, 4, 1, 9};
f1[foo, list, 3]
```

> {foo[1], 4, 3, 7, foo[2], 7, 6, 4, 8, 2, 3, 4, foo[1], 9}

```
f2[foo, list, 3]
```

> {foo[1], 4, 3, 7, foo[2], 7, 6, 4, 8, 2, 3, 4, foo[1], 9}

```
f1[foo, list, -3]
```

> {1, 4, 3, 7, 2, foo[7], 6, 4, foo[8], 2, 3, 4, 1, foo[9]}

```
f2[foo, list, -3]
```

> {1, 4, 3, 7, 2, foo[7], 6, 4, foo[8], 2, 3, 4, 1, foo[9]}